Why metal objects (like a door, a desk, or a machine) get charged?
I work at the University in a office at the science building. At my workplace, every time someone touches a metal object (like a door, a desk, or a machine), they receive a small electric shock. This happens frequently at different times of the day.
We have at the office five PC. PC never shut down since their are making simulations many times. Also we are in the science building, but I think that there is not any experimental lab nearby.
What could be causing this, and how can we prevent or reduce its occurrence? I would appreciate any explanation related to static electricity or possible environmental factors contributing to this phenomenon.

Is there carpet in the office? Do you sit in plastic chairs? What's the humidity like? Do you have air-conditioning?


What could be causing this, and how can we prevent or reduce its occurrence? I would appreciate any explanation related to static electricity or possible environmental factors contributing to this phenomenon.

"Static" electricity in the home or office is usually caused by the triboelectric effect, which occurs when two different materials rub against one another. For example shoes on carpet, or clothing on a plastic covered chair. The classic children's experiment uses an inflated balloon rubbed against a person's hair.
One of the significant environmental factors that allows "static" charges to build up to a point where their discharge can be felt is humidity. When the humidity is low, the body being charged may not discharge until it comes in contact with a metal object. When the humidity is high, the body may discharge before there is significant build-up, and this discharge goes un-noticed.

That's interesting, I'm goin to check if the cheeks doesn't occur when it's rainy. But can triboelectric effect explain why the charge accumulate on the metal objects rather than in the rubbed ones?

@PabloDiezSilva Generally it is a non-metallic object that becomes charged, and they discharge through a metal object. The door knob is not rubbing against something, but the clothes on your body or your shoes do rub against things, and that charges your body. An exception to the above rule is a van de Graaff generator, where a large metallic sphere is charged.

We though that was the metal object what is charged because it only happens in the office, and usually when you arrive in the morning. So it made no sense to us that something on the office was charging us. Also it happens to everybody, and not two times in a row. If I touch the metal, I receive the shock, if my workmates tocuh afterwards, they are not shocked.

@PabloDiezSilva is there carpet or a mat in either the hallway or in the office? Do your chairs have synthetic material covering? There might be some reason for the door knobs to be charged, but that would not be the usual cause of static electric shocks. Do the doors rub against a carpet on the floor?

No, there is not carpet in all the way to the office, not even plastic materials (I think that the stairs are made of some metal plate)

As said in the answer of @MathKeepsMeBusy, it is not the metal object itself that gets charged, it is your body, including your hand.
But it's worthwhile thinking about why the metal object participates in the "sudden discharge", a.k.a. the shock.
Suppose that an object with excess electrons approaches a metal object. Metals in general, like the metal in your doorknob, are good conductors. This mean that the electrons can move around in the metal a lot more easily than they can in non-metals like your body. Now your fingertip, filled with its share of the excess electrons in your body, approaches the doorknob. The electrons in the doorknob feel the repulsive force of the electrons in your finger, and they move away. A potential will then build up between your negatively charged fingertip and the newly positively charged region near surface of the doorknob. ZAP, electrons jump across that potential.
